# How to save file_get_contents in Mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, fwrite

I'm creating a callback URL on my server. I need to save the `file_get_contents` in a log file and my MySQL database.

The log file is okay, as i am able to log and view the decoded data, but i need the same in my database.

```
try {
    header("Content-Type:application/json");

    $postData = file_get_contents('php://input');
    $filePath = "\messages.log";

    //error log
    $errorLog = "\errors.log";

    $decodedData = json_decode($postData, true);

    $service_id = $decodedData['service_id'];
    $trans_id = $decodedData['trans_id'];
    $status = $decodedData['status'];
    $partner = $decodedData['partner'];

    $con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$con) {
        die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO test_table (service_id, trans_id, status, 
        partner)
        VALUES
        ('$service_id', '$trans_id', '$status', '$partner' )";

    if (!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {
        echo mysqli_error($con);
    }

    $file = fopen($filePath, "a");

    fwrite($file, $postData);
    fwrite($file, "\r\n");
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    //appending exception to file
    $logErr = fopen($errorLog, "a");
    fwrite($logErr, $ex->getMessage());
    fwrite($logErr, "\r\n");
    fclose($logErr);
}

fwrite($file, "\r\n");
fclose($file);
```

No errors in the Log file and nothing is saved in the database

Comment: There is nothing special about the return from file_get_contents, you can save it in the DB as either Text, or Blob.  The bigger question is the size of this data and it's impact on table performance.

Comment: `$errorLog = "\errors.log";` might be a wrong path. \ is an escape character

Comment: Solved, i had an issue with Data Types in my database.. Thanks guys..